# Correct configuration for collaborative development of an R package on a shared drive

Tags: r, git, rstudio, collaboration

We have two people on two computers. Computer A has a shared drive with Computer B. We would like to collaborate on an R package. My understanding is that we have three ingredients:

- The R Project source code
- The installed R package
- The git repository

Currently we share all three over the shared drive. However, this doesn't allow us to work on separate Git branches (unless there's something I'm missing), since we're working on the same source files.

What would be the correct way of arranging these files to allow both users to work on separate Git branches? Would both have local versions of the R Project, and work on a common git repository? If so, would it be better to also have separate installations of the package, or a share a single one on the shared drive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The capabilities you require are best supported within Git. Ideally you should structure your work to minimize the degree to which multiple people are working on a given file at the same time to reduce the effort to merge multiple versions of the same file back into the master branch. An alternate strategy would be to make frequent commits and pulls to reduce the complexity of merges. A thorough treatment of branching strategies in Git are available in Chapter 3 of [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell).